# Wifi network Connection detection takes too long time in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, networking, connection

Internet **connection detection in my Wifi** network (Using Desktop Computer ) **takes too long time**, after upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10.

I have only basic knowledge in ubuntu.So please help me by providing step by step explanations to establish a quicker network connection?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Answer (score -2):

Update the System.

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

After this command try whether your wifi working or not. If not means do the following

Then you have to remove the bcmwl kernel source:

```
 sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then again install :

```
 sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: How could you possibly know that he has a Broadcom wireless card and, moreover, one that is supported by the STA driver?